# How can I make this section of my webpage responsive?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

Here's the link to the page I made: https://thawing-savannah-89995.herokuapp.com/
This is my first webpage I've made without help using only a PSD.

Here's a SS of the area I'm having issues with and keeps breaking when I shrink the browser size.  This layout was very difficult for me to think through and I don't think it should've been.  How can I better design the html and CSS for that part?

[image]

Comment: Hmm too much to explain. First. Congratulations. It looks much nicer than my first design. Check out http://getbootstrap.com/ especially http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid Its all about having a css grid system, that rearrange your website based on your screen width. In addition you usually hide things that dont look good on small screens, or adjust your content / texts with shorter versions.

Comment: My suggestion would be to find an existing responsive framework (Bootstrap/Foundation come to mind) and structure your HTML according to that. Identify different sections in your design and how they correspond to elements defined in your chosen framework, then write your code - it's much easier to build a responsive layout from the ground up, rather than trying to work it into existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep at the time of this post to comment. Sorry, I would if I could.

I suggest using a thing in css called `flexbox`. It takes a little extra work instead of Bootstrap or 960 or something, but in combination with percentage units, and even maybe `vh/vw` if you want to be new age.

[This guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) explains it better than I could ever hope to; basically, it's a dynamic alignment system. Centering is made trivial, compared to the alternatives. Keep in mind, you might need some @media breakpoints, mostly to change the `flex-direction`.

It has recently gained [almost](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (sorry IE) universal browser support. If you do care about IE, use a shim like [flexibility](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility).

If you do want to use bootstrap-like grid systems, there are better [alternatives](http://susy.oddbird.net/), if you want to look into them. Personally not a fan of bootstrap (anymore...) but whatever floats your boat I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The best lesson I learned with creating Responsive sites is to design how you want this to look on a mobile device and work your way up to the Desktop.

I can suggest that you use Twitter Bootstap or Foundation as well as downloading responsive templates. Read as many articles you can find about different techniques that you can find to help you best understand the concept of how do to this.